# Recommended quadrotor for using hector_slam package

Tags: quadcopter, slam, navigation, hector-slam, hector-quadrotor

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Which would be the recommended quadrotor for using hector_slam. I am currently trying the nicely documented tutorial : hector_quadrotor ( [link](http://wiki.ros.org/hector_quadrotor) ) . I was wondering on which all quadrotor everyone is using the hector_slam package.

While looking for this answer, I came across these links:
http://answers.ros.org/question/9101/which-quadrotor-has-the-best-ros-support/ 
http://answers.ros.org/question/12412/autonomously-flying-quadrotor/ 
http://wiki.ros.org/MikroKopter/Tutorials/shared_control 
http://wiki.ros.org/Robots#UAVs
http://www.ros.org/news/robots/uavs/

I could not figure out which quadrotor was used for development and testing of Hector SLAM. So with my finding, my best option (might be only) would be Ascending Technologies Pelican. Has anyone tried using Hector SLAM on Pelican ?

-Suraj

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/137701/recommended-quadrotor-for-using-hector_slam-package/) by [ss_robotics](https://answers.ros.org/users/348/ss_robotics/) on ROS Answers with karma: 75 on 2014-03-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-03-09**:
According to their paper, hector_slam was developed on a ground vehicle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There isn´t really a specific platform that I heard about to work best. Ideally, your platform should

- have a Hokuyo UTM-30 (or similar)
  LIDAR
- provide enough computing power (old
  Atom Z530 was sufficient, most more
  modern options should be sufficient)
- provide sensible IMU data (especially
  roll/pitch). That´s basically a given
  for a quadrotor, as it wouldn´t be
  able to fly otherwise ;)

A few examples of (mostly Mikrokopter based) quads running hector_mapping can be found in [this playlist on YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL0E462904E5D35E29). [Here in Fig. 4](http://www.gkmm.tu-darmstadt.de/publications/files/kohlbrecher2013opensource.pdf) you can see an example of running a bag-file of the CCNY dataset through hector_mapping (originally recorded with a Asctec quad).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-03-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ss_robotics](https://answers.ros.org/users/348/ss_robotics/) on 2014-03-23**:
Thanks Stefan.